# how to take python conditional expressions in a str ()

Tags: python, conditional-statements

code python 3.6

```
#database contains rows (relationships) of the form:
# (autoincremented id, booleans, column3, column4)
# ejm: (1, "A || B || C", "data1", "data2")


def function (booleans):
     global list1
     global list2

     '' 'takes `booleans` and queries the database to retrieve
        column3, and column4 '' '

     list1 = column3
     list2 = column4

     return list1, list2


if A:
     if B:
         if C:
             function ('A || B || C')
         elif D:
             function ('A || B || D')
     elif E:
         if C:
             function ('A || E || C')
        
print (list1)
print (list2)

# this is olnly an example
#if `B` is `False` then `E` would have to be `True`
```

The program will only take a path in the conditionals according to the situation and will print the lists assigned by the booleans.

So the question would be, **how to give the argument automatically to function (bool) without doing it manually in the conditionals?**. sds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand the problem correctly, but if I do, the best thing to do would be to replace your separate variables `A`, `B` etc. with a dict:

```
dic = {}
dic['A'] = True
dic['B'] = False
dic['C'] = True
# etc.
s = ' || '.join([k for k, v in dic.items() if v]) 
# for the above data, s is now 'A || C' 
function(s)
```